# ERROR: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand' to type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand'

Tags: c#, postgresql, oracle, npgsql, pgadmin

I'm encountering an issue when sending an HTTP GET request in my code, resulting in the following error message:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand' to type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand'.
```

The problematic line of code with the breakpoint looks like this:

```cs
bool add = !((OracleCommand)command).Parameters.Contains(name);
```

I'm unsure if this issue is related to the class I've created, which includes an asynchronous method for executing a stored procedure:

```cs
public async Task SP_WEB_OBTIENE_DESTINO_PLACES_ASYNC(string V_DESTINO_ID)
{
    MainBaseClass result = new MainBaseClass();

    using (IDbConnection db = GetConnection())
    {
        var par = new DynamicParameters();
        par.Add("@V_DESTINATION_ID", V_DESTINATION_ID);

        var list = await db.QueryAsync<LugaresWeb>(
            "SELECT * FROM public.sp_web_gets_destination_places(v_destination_id => @v_destination_id)",
            par,
            commandType: CommandType.Text);

        result.datas = list.Cast<IDictionary<string, object?>>();
        result.affectedRows = list.Count();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Here's the definition of the `LugaresWeb` class:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace guiapemexservices.Core.Models.Lugares
{
    public class LugaresWeb
    {
        public string? placetype { get; set; }
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Latitude { get; set; }
        public string? Length { get; set; }
        public string? Address { get; set; }
        public string? TurnType { get; set; }
        public string? SubType { get; set; }
        public string? ClassificationType { get; set; }
        public string? Active { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I attempted to modify the code within the `public async` method and the `IDbConnection`, but other methods with the same connection seem to work fine, retrieving the expected data.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you trying to cast `Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand` to `OracleCommand`?

Comment: Why am I migrating from Oracle to PostgreSQL?

Comment: No.Why are you performing this cast? ))

Comment: Change the code to  `(NpgsqlCommand)command`. Do not forget to import need namespaces

Comment: this looks like Dapper code; is that right? if so, do you actually *have* any code like `bool add = !((OracleCommand)command).Parameters.Contains(name);` ? or is that something that it has spat out by decompiling the IL at runtime? although I'm confused there too, because Dapper doesn't emit custom code for `DynamicParameters`. Also, is this Dapper? or Dapper.AOT?

Comment: It's something that appears when I compile the solution, it's like it's reading that I'm trying to connect to Oracle, and not PostgreSQL

Comment: @CarlSA is `bool add = !((OracleCommand)command).Parameters.Contains(name);` part of your code? Do you have a full [mre]? If don't - please share .csproj file. What is `GetConnection`?